# Can css-loader return just a string?

Tags: javascript, webpack

In my webpack config if I wanted to use `css-loader` to then use `file-loader` how can I get `css-loader` to do it's magic and then still return what `file-loader` wants so it can save it as a `.css`

Example config

```
{
    test: /\.scss$/,
    loaders: [
        'file-loader?name=[name].css',
        'css-loader',
        'autoprefixer-loader',
        'sass-loader'
    ]
}
```

Can it be done?

Comment: I don't think that this possible currently. It's actually a feature request. Would you mind creating an issue at https://github.com/webpack/css-loader? Do you know the [extract-text-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin)? It serves a similar purpose.

Comment: Ah nice I hadn't seen the extract-text-webpack-plugin, I'll put in an issue. Thanks for the reply.